# ¿Cómo recuperar el valor de un mat input y validar que no este vacío usando reactive forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Tengo las siguientes tablas que se llenan con diferentes servicios, y lo que hacen es mostrar lo que hay en dos tablas de catálogos.

Es la primera vez que estoy implementado formularios reactivos, y lo estoy tratando de implementar en las siguientes tablas, donde se puede modificar el valor de la **descripción**, este campo se encuentra dentro de un mat table.
Lo que quiero hacer es recuperar el valor del campo **descripcionProducto** y validar que no este vacío ese campo, es decir que cuando borren el valor del campo se ponga en rojo y diga algo como no puede ir vacio,
no se si asi como tengo el forumlario es correcto para que sea reactivo

html

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          PRODUCTO
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <form [formGroup]="productoTable">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="idProducto">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idProducto }}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcionProducto">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>PRODUCTO</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [value]="element.descripcionProducto" 
                formControlName="descripcionProducto"/>
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </ng-container>


          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
        </table>
      </form>
      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
      </mat-paginator>
    </mat-expansion-panel>

    <!----------   TABLA SUBPRODUCTO   -->
    <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          SUBPRODUCTO
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceSubProducto" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="idSubProducto">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idSubProducto }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcionSubProducto">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>SUBPRODUCTO</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [value]="element.descripcionSubProducto" />
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </ng-container>


        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsSubProd"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsSubProd"></tr>
      </table>
      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
      </mat-paginator>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'pruebaforms';
  productoTable!: FormGroup;
  panelOpenState = false;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['idProducto', 'descripcionProducto'];
  displayedColumnsSubProd: string[] = ['idSubProducto', 'descripcionSubProducto'];
  catProducto: CatalogoProducto[] = [];
  catSubProducto: CatalogoSubProducto[] = [];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  
  constructor(private catService: CatalogosServiceService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerCatalogoProducto();
    this.obtenerCatalogoSubProducto();
  }

  //obtiene la lista del catalogo producto
  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerCatalogoProducto() {
    this.catService.obtenerCatProd().subscribe((response) => {
      this.catProducto = response.data;
      console.log('PRUEBA  CAT PROD  ', response.data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.catProducto);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la lista del catalogo subproducto
  dataSourceSubProducto: any;
  private obtenerCatalogoSubProducto() {
    this.catService.obtenerCatSubProd().subscribe((response) => {
      this.catSubProducto = response.data;
      console.log('PRUEBA CAT SUBPROD  ', response.data);
      this.dataSourceSubProducto = new MatTableDataSource(this.catSubProducto);
      this.dataSourceSubProducto.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: En ninguna parte estableces el formulario, solamente tienes `productoTable!: FormGroup;` pero no tienes los campos para validar. Checa la documentación: [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Estás bindeando el formGroup pero: A) no tienes el formGroup instanciado en el .ts, solo lo declaras y nunca lo instancias. B) necesitas pasarle al input el control, lo más cómodo es usar `formControlName="nombreDelCampoEnElFormGroup"`, de esta manera quedará "enlazado" al `formcontrol` de tu `FormGroup`. A continuación puedes acceder a cualquier parte de tu formulario a través de `form.value.campoQueQUierasAcceder` directamente.